# How to get rid off the error: "__new__() got multiple values for argument 'order'" doing an ARIMA model in Python

Tags: python, arima

I am doing a simple ARIMAX model (1,0,0) with one dependent variable y, one independent variable x with 49 observations as a time series.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/gaetanlion/Google Drive/Python/Arima/df.xlsx', sheet_name = 'final')

from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
endo = df['y']
exo = df['x']

''' Doing a ARIMA(1,0,0) '''
model = ARIMA(endo, exo, order = (1,0,0)).fit()
```

When I run this simple model, I get the mentioned error:

```
TypeError: __new__() got multiple values for argument 'order'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to resolve this coding issue.  But, I am not so sure it is the best way to resolve it.

```
model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(endo, exo, order =(1,0,0)).fit() # This works
model = ARIMA(endo, exo, order = (1,0,0)).fit() # This does not work
```